fo:list-block alignment problem- how to align bottom?
Good morning!
Thanks for looking. I have some lovely MIL-STD-40051 XML (DTD 6.5.3) and a style sheet question.
This is my first encounter with a list-block.  I found this site helpful to get my head around the concept.
text
This image was particularly helpful.
visual guide to list-block layout
If this was a table, I would say the problem is that the two cells are aligning to the TOP of the cell, and I need them to align to the BOTTOM of the cell.
But it's a list-block, and ... I have no idea how to implement that with a list-block.  I spent about four hours experimenting, no joy, and have decided to try and ask the community for help.
DTD snippet, simplified a little:
<!ELEMENT tsindx.messageword (applicable?, title, (tsindx.messageword-category+ | tsindx.messageword-entry+))
<!ELEMENT tsindx.messageword-category (applicable?, title, tsindx.messageword-entry+)>
<!ELEMENT tsindx.messageword-entry (applicable?, messageword+, xref)>

Style sheet (xsl) snippets:
<xsl:template match="tsindx.messageword">
    <fo:block font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt" provisional-distance-between-starts="29pc" provisional-label-separation="0pt" space-before.conditionality="discard" space-before.maximum="12pt" space-before.minimum="8pt" space-before.optimum="10pt">
[snip]

<xsl:template match="tsindx.messageword-category">
    <fo:block font-weight="bold" space-before.conditionality="discard" space-before.maximum="8pt" space-before.minimum="5pt" space-before.optimum="6pt" span="all" start-indent="0pt">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tsindx.messageword-entry"/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<!-- this is the bit that produces my output -->

<xsl:template match="tsindx.messageword-entry">
    <fo:list-block>
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:block start-indent="6pt" space-after="8pt">
                    <xsl:number count="tsindx.messageword-entry" format="1." from="tsindxwp" level="any"/>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&#x2003;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="messageword"/>
                    <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body relative-align="baseline">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="xref"/>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </fo:list-block>
</xsl:template>


(   is an em-space, slightly wider than normal spaces.)
PDF output looks like this:
--PDF--
AIR SYSTEM TROUBLESHOOTING

Air System Does Not Reach Operating Pressure, Or Loses Pressure WP 0021

During Operation . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
BRAKE SYSTEM TROUBLESHOOTING

Trailer Brakes Overheat, Drag, Or Do Not Release . . . . . . . . WP 0025

Trailer Brakes Unevenly, Pulls To One Side, Or Brakes Do Not Apply WP 0026

Vehicle Brakes Overheat, Drag, Or Do Not Release . . . . . . . . WP 0028

Vehicle Brakes Unevenly, Pulls To One Side, Or Do Not Apply .. . WP 0029


--end pdf--
Generally correct, but #1 and #3 need some work.
FIRST PROBLEM:
If this was a table, I would say the cells need to be aligned bottom rather than aligned top.  But it's a list-block, and apparently they work differently....
The list-label-item  (title) is long enough to wrap down to a second line, which is fine.
The list-item-body  WP 0021 is populating aligned with the top of the list-item-label  (title) instead of aligned with the bottom of the list-item-label, at the end of the leader dots.
I'm getting this:

Air System Does Not Reach Operating Pressure, Or Loses Pressure WP 0021

During Operation . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
where the list-item-body  is aligned with the upper line of list-item-label  and not the leader dots.
The reviewers are complaining that it looks like
"Air System Does Not Reach Operating Pressure, Or Loses Pressure WP 0021 During Operation"
and I can't really disagree.
What I want is this:

Air System Does Not Reach Operating Pressure, Or Loses Pressure

During Operation . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . WP 0021
where if the  list-item-label  title is long enough to wrap,  the list-item-body  populates after the leader dots, aligned with the bottom of list-item-label.
I have been editing the style sheet with notepad++ and Oxygen.  Oxygen gives me a ridiculous number of attribute options, none of which have accomplished what I want.
SECOND PROBLEM (lower priority but still would be nice to fix)
It would be nice to be able to limit the length of list-item-label  field to be a little shorter and wrap the text to a second line.  The lack of a leader line for long titles looks odd.
Current output is this:

Trailer Brakes Unevenly, Pulls To One Side, Or Brakes Do Not Apply WP 0026

Where list-item-label  runs all the way to list-item-body  and there is no leader line.
This would be better:

Trailer Brakes Unevenly, Pulls To One Side, Or Brakes Do

Not Apply. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .. . . .  . . . WP 0026
With list-item-label  constrained a little shorter so there is always a leader line.
Fixing problem #2 would be contingent on fixing problem #1 and getting the list-item-body  to align with the bottom of list-item-label .
(Sorry this is verbose; I'm trying to make sure I have a full explanation of the issues.)
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.
Dan
I have tried a bunch of different attribute changes for the two fo:blocks.  So far, no success.

It seems to me that only the number would need to go in the fo:list-item-label, and that the entry text, the leader(s), and the xref could go in the fo:list-item-body.
For discussion on how to use fo:leader, see the examples at https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.leader-expansion and the fo:leader samples from the XSL-FO Samples Collection at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples. Particularly see https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples#axf-last-right-justify-1, with PDF at https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/line/axf-last-right-justify-1.pdf?hsLang=en. The fo:block-container sample from that is:
<fo:block-container text-align="justify" text-align-last="right">
<fo:block>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing cons equat elit...
<fo:leader />
<fo:leader leader-length.optimum="100%" />
<fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">Antenna House</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>

If you are using Antenna House Formatter, you could instead use axf:tab-stops, as also shown in that sample.

Processing via Arbortext 8.2.  I know it's not being handled by Antenna House.

Yeah, that was it.  Had to putter with a couple of other things, but that was the solution.  Thanks for the prod to re-write it correctly rather than trying to patch bad code.

Sometimes the fix is to stop trying to patch around the customer's bad code, and just re-write it correctly.
The fix was to use the xsl the way it was intended.
I moved <messageword> and <leader> from <list-item-label> to  (where they should have been) and adjusted provisional-distance-between-starts to 20 pts.
<fo:list-item-label  end-indent="label-end()">
  <fo:block start-indent="6pt">
    <xsl:number count="tsindx.messageword-entry" format="1." from="tsindxwp" level="any"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&#x2003;</xsl:text>
  </fo:block>
</fo:list-item-label>
<fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="messageword"/>
  <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="xref"/>
</fo:list-item-body>

Output now wraps correctly and no additional patching to get the alignment is necessary.
Thanks for looking. :)
